# Printing 132000 lines in a file using Java

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to print 132_000 lines in a file.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CredentialTemplate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Declaring output file
        File fout = new File(
                "D:\\testout.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

        int start = 0, stop = 0;
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Start:  ");
        start = x.nextInt();
        System.out.print("End:  ");
        stop = x.nextInt();

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++) {

            System.out.println("Importeduser" + i + ",Test,4," + r.nextInt(9)
                    + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)+ r.nextInt(9)+",0,"
                    + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)
                    + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)
                    + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9));
            bw.write("Importeduser" + i + ",Test,4," + r.nextInt(9)
                    + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)+ r.nextInt(9)+",0,"
                    + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)
                    + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)
                    + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9));
            bw.newLine();

        }

    }

}
```

Problem i am facing:
I am not getting all 1,32,000 lines in txt file.
Sometimes its 1,31,693 lines or 1,31,721 lines.

But in the console i can able to see all 1,32,000 printed.

Please let me me know if am doing anything wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try flushing the BUFFERED writer before exiting :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't closing your `Writer`. You can use a `finally` block, or you can use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). The first might look like,

```
try {
    for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
        String line = "Importeduser" + i + ",Test,4," + r.nextInt(9)
                + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)
                + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + ",0," + r.nextInt(9)
                + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)
                + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)
                + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9);
        System.out.println(line);
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
    }
} finally {
    if (bw != null) {
        bw.close();
    }
    if (fos != null) {
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

And the second (`try-with-resources`) might look like

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                fos))) {
    for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
        String line = "Importeduser" + i + ",Test,4," + r.nextInt(9)
                + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)
                + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + ",0," + r.nextInt(9)
                + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)
                + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9)
                + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9) + r.nextInt(9);
        System.out.println(line);
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Close your writer to write the remaining data

do `bw.close()` at the end of the program